# Is there a way to start a foreach loop in the middle of an array?

Tags: php

I have an array of months. I want to iterate through each month as the key to get the values for each one but...

I want to start at the current month, run the foreach and come back around to the next year stopping on the 12th month.

I've tried creating a separate array of months based on the current month, but it seems a little janky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `do/while` loop with a modulo counter e.g.

```
$months = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
$i = $current_month = 5;
do {
    echo $months[$i] . "\n";
    $i = ($i + 1) % 12;
} while ($i != $current_month);
```

Output:

```
Jun 
Jul 
Aug 
Sep 
Oct 
Nov 
Dec 
Jan 
Feb 
Mar 
Apr 
May
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uBcM3)

If you also need to maintain a year counter, you can use this code, which increments the year when the month wraps around:

```
$year = 2018;
$i = $current_month = 5;
do {
    echo $months[$i] . " $year\n";
    $i = ($i + 1) % 12;
    if ($i == 0) $year++;
} while ($i != $current_month);
```

Output:

```
Jun 2018
...
Dec 2018
Jan 2019
...
May 2019
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sHl3O)

Comment: The entire second year is required to be looped. e.g. Jun-Dec 2019 AND Jan-Dec 2020.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think so, I think the 12th month is 11 months after the first month, not December of the next year. If OP meant for it to be December, he could have just said that.

Comment: Awesome. My bad if so, you still have my vote anyway! :)

Comment: @Jonathan I guess we'll find out what OP really meant when they accept an answer... :-)

Comment: @Nick Spot on. I just had to get the current month -1 and it worked excellent!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `continue` statement!

```
$current_month = 6; # just assuming, you can change as per your requirement.
foreach ($month_array as $k => $v) {
   if ($k < 5) continue;
   // your code here to go after your current month to end of the year's month
}
```

Comment: I think Dave S is wanting the array to loop around back to the beginning months (but for the following year). Example: Starts Oct18, Nov18, Dec18, Jan19, Feb19, and so on... This would stop at the end of the year (Dec18).

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry my bad !! Then I just misread that - I want to start at the current month, run the foreach and come back around to the next year **stopping on the 12th month**.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `for` statement instead?

```
$months = [
   'January', 
   'February',
   '...',
];

$currentMonth = 5; // 0 for January, 11 for December

for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $index = ($currentMonth + $i) % 12;

    echo $months[$index] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will print

```
June
July
August
September
...
```